# Make SCNNode move in facing direction after rotation

Tags: swift, xcode

I am very new to SceneKit, only having worked with 2D applications so far. Although this question has already been asked, I am not advanced enough to understand the answers. I have a SCNNode that I want to move forward no matter where it's facing after any rotation is applied. Here is my current code for my forward, right, and left actions:

```
func moveForward() {
    
    let moveForwardAction = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:1) , duration: 0.5)
    let startForwardAction = SCNAction.repeatForever((SCNAction.sequence([moveForwardAction])))
    carNode.runAction(startForwardAction)
    
}

func moveLeft() {
    let turnLeftAction = SCNAction.rotateTo(x: toRadians(angle: 0), y: toRadians(angle: 90), z: 0, duration: 2.0, usesShortestUnitArc: true)
    let startLeftAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.sequence([turnLeftAction]))
    carNode.runAction(startLeftAction)
    
}

func moveRight() {
    let turnRightAction = SCNAction.rotateBy(x: toRadians(angle: 0), y: toRadians(angle: 90), z: 0, duration: 0.5)
    let startRightAction = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.sequence([turnRightAction]))
    carNode.runAction(startRightAction)
    
}
```

Is there any way someone can dumb it down for me and tell me what code I need to be inputting to get my desired outcome?